# ASP.Net TreeView control Expand/Collapse not working when opened in iframe

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iframe, treeview

I have one ASP.NET TreeView control and I'm displaying it in Bootstrap modal dialog using iframe, it is displaying properly but if I collapse/expand any treenode checkbox which contains child nodes it is not collapsing/expanding.

If I display this TreeView control in normal HTML page(not in iframe) it is working fine only in iframe it is not expanding/collapsing.

```
 <asp:TreeView ID="treeEditRes" runat="server" ShowCheckBoxes="All"  ShowExpandCollapse="true" ShowLines="false" ExpandDepth="1" NodeStyle-HorizontalPadding="3" PopulateNodesFromClient="true" SelectedNodeStyle-BackColor="Gray" OnTreeNodeExpanded="Node_Expand" OnTreeNodeCollapsed="Node_Collapse" >
      <SelectedNodeStyle CssClass="GridHead" />
 </asp:TreeView>
```

Even I added events for Expand & Collapse if I expand/collapse node it is triggering those events but it is not expanding/collapsing.

```
    void Node_Expand(Object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Node.Expand();
    }
    void Node_Collapse(Object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Node.Collapse();
    }
```

Please suggest me if the above code requires any changes.